# Replacing DIP switch with a miniature switch

Tags: switches

On this schematic, I'd like to replace one of the DIP switch with a 3-way switch that connects only the x3 or only the x6 or only the x8, as I only need to implement these positions. What kind of switch should I use? The tiniest possible as it's to add to a musical instrument.

[image]

Comment: google `SP3T switch` ... Single Pole 3 Throw ... get a DP3T if you want to wire indicator LEDs

Comment: From what I recall of the 4017, I expect that even a 3 position, centre off  switch would work as you could permanently wire the x8 position closed and connect the switch contacts to the x3 and x6 position. Do you have any preference for a slide/toggle/rocker style?

Comment: see the 4017 datasheet for the appropriate reset circuit.

Comment: that switch at the top can connect `input` to `f_out`

Answer (score 0):

A three-position wafer switch (rotary action) would be the
usual choice; DIP switches are perhaps smaller, however.
As I read the diagram, one should never connect multiple Q (output)
nodes together, and the DIP switch does not lock out that possibility.
It seems you'd want a three-position (SP3T) switch?  Or,
to keep things simple looking, one ten-position and one three-position (SP10T, SP3T)?